# Implications of Integral linear program

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, mathematical-programming

Let $(P)$ an *Integer Linear Program*, where we aim to find $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ maximizing a linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ under some linear constraints $Ax\le b$

Let $(P^*)$ be its relaxation, which means that the constraint $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ is replaced by $x\in [0,1]^n$.

Then, suppose that we know that
$$
\max_{x\in \{0,1\}^n} \left\{f(x), Ax\le b\right\} = \max_{x\in [0,1]^n} \left\{f(x), Ax\le b\right\}
$$

Is it possible, given an optimal solution $y^*\in[0,1]^n$ of $(P^*)$ (that we have found with simplex algorithm for instance), to find an optimal solution $y\in\{0,1\}^n$ of $(P)$ (*i.e.* such that $f(y)=f(y^*)$ and $Ay\le b$),  say in polynomial time ? Or is there any concrete conter-example ?

Comment: What do you mean with "the value of these two programs match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not possible unless P=NP. So, it is unlikely that such a method exists.

Many NP-hard problems can be modeled as an integer program, we take 3SAT for an example. Suppose we are given a 3SAT instance with clauses $C_i$ and variables $v$. For each clause, denote the variables that appear positive by $C_i^+$ and the variables that appear negative by $C_i^-$. Now, consider the following integer program $P$:

$\begin{align} 
\max 1 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad & \sum_{v\in C_i^+} x_v + \sum_{v\in C_i^-} (1-x_v) \geq 1 \text{ for all } i\\
& x_v \in \{0,1\} \text{ for all } v
\end{align}$

Note that $P$ has a feasible solution if and only if our 3SAT instance is satisfiable. (a solution to $P$ corresponds to a satisfying assignment of the 3SAT instance) This solution is then 'optimal' as well, as all feasible solutions of $P$ have the same cost. This means that also the relaxation $P^*$ must have the same cost if $P$ is feasible. So, we will assume that the given 3SAT instance is satisfiable, so that the costs of $P$ and $P^*$ are equal.

Now, suppose we have some method to find a solution for $P$ from a solution $y\in [0,1]^d$ for $P^*$. As $P^*$ is a normal linear program, we can find such a solution $y$ in polynomial time, by using e.g. the ellipsoid method. Then, our method gives us a solution for $P$ in polynomial time. But this solution gives a satisfying assignment for our initial 3SAT problem, which means we can find a satisfying assignment to 3SAT problems in polynomial time. As finding a satisfying assignment for 3SAT is NP-hard (even if we know the instance has a satisfying assignment), this means that P=NP

---

I suppose that intuitively, what is going on here is that knowing the value of a solution to an integer program does not tell you a lot about the specific variable assignment. In a way, this is because the 'complexity' of a linear program lies mostly in its constraints, rather than the goal function.

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that the simplex algorithm will always find an optimal solution that is a vertex of the polytope defined by $A x \leq b$. Hence if none of the vertices of the polytope are integral then it cannot find the integral solution.

For example, consider maximising $x + y$ subject to the constraints that $x + y \leq 4$, $y - x \leq 1$ and $x - y \leq 1$ as shown in the figure below. Then the optimal solution of this as an integral linear programming problem is $(2, 2)$ however the solution found by the simplex method for the relaxed problem will either be $(1.5, 2.5)$ or $(2.5, 1.5)$.

[image]

Note however that this situation can only occur if the relaxed version of the problem has more than one optimal solution. If the relaxed version has a unique optimum $y^*$ then thanks the equality that you have supposed $y^*$ will be integral and so the optimum solution to the integral problem.

Comment: Although it is indeed true that the relaxed solution vector $y$ often isn't integral, this doesn't mean that there is no algorithm to construct an integral solution from such a vector.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  The question is looking for a way to find a solution in polynomial time.  The simplex algorithm is not a polynomial-time algorithm: it can take exponential time.  So, suggesting to use the simplex algorithm doesn't meet the requirements in the question.